# ExpandableListView centains a link does not expand

Tags: android, android-widget, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView contains a link, it does not expand when has a link, and i want the link is clickable.

code like this:

```
<ExpandableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

and:

```
<TextView android:layout_below="@id/screenName" android:layout_alignLeft="@id/screenName" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:autoLink="web|email" android:linksClickable="true" android:id="@+id/text"  />
```

Comment: It might help to include the ExpandableListView part of the code.  What you show is just a textView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the link clickable and the list item clickable at the same time. It's one or the other.