# Android ExpandableListView with clickable links in child TextView won't expand properly

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, expandablelistview

First, I have searched for similiar questions but none that I have found have been answered (except to say that it is impossible, which I doubt).

[Android ExpandableListView with clickable links in child TextView won't expand when touching TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824187/android-expandablelistview-with-clickable-links-in-child-textview-wont-expand-w)

[ExpandableListView centains a link does not expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151116/expandablelistview-centains-a-link-does-not-expand)

I have an expandable list adapter that may or may not contain links within a textview in the item's groupview. Here is what is currently happening:

- when I touch one of these textviews without a link in it, it expands properly (this is what I want)
- when I touch one of these textviews with a link in it directly on the highlighted text, it opens the proper website in the external browser (this is what i want)
- when I touch one of these textviews with a link in it on non-highlighted text that is not part of the link, it does nothing (this is NOT what I want.)

how do I get it so that if I touch one of these textviews with a link in it on the non-highlighted text it expands and shows the childviews?

relevant code:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.docket_layout, null);
    }
    TextView docketTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.docketHeader);
    docketTitle.setText(myDockets.getDocket(groupPosition).title);
    return v;
}
```

and the relevant XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/docketHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    />
```

Thank you in advance for you help